# Revoke not working on external schema in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have been trying to revoke all permissions from an external schema for a particular user group/user.
Commands seem to execute, but the changes are not effective.
Using this command:

```
revoke ALL on schema mixpanel_db from group read_group;
```

Using TablePlus as the client application. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, did you find a solution by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, no luck. I ended up deleting the user